# How to cut through a font in half in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

How do you cut a vertical line though a font to split in half?

Answer (score 1):

Object > Expand

then create a box that'll indicate your cut.
Now select both objects and cut it with the pathfinder.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a **Clipping Mask** in the shape of a J on a *raster* image. You can't cut the raster image, but you can alter the clipping mask.

It's assumed the "J" has already been converted to outlines to create the clipping mask. If not, select the "J" and choose `Type > Convert to Outlines` first.

- Draw a line where you want to split
- Select the line and just the clipping shape (J) do **NOT** select the
  raster image
- Click the **Divide** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**
- *You will loose the clipping mask, that’s okay*
- `Object > Ungroup`
- `Object > Compound Shape > Make`
- Select the shape (J) and the raster image
- `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`

You can then use the Direct Selection Tool to move each half of the letter. However, you need to stay within the area of the raster image for the mask to work. Otherwise, the edges of the raster image will be seen inside the pieces of the clipping mask.

<sub>Larger (KB) gif.. it may take a minute to load</sub>

[image]

There are additional methods if you want each piece to be independent objects and not bound by the dimensions of the masked raster image.

- Rather than making a compound Shape, you just copy the raster image and create 2 clipping masks - one for each half.